# GSPD information stream timing out after 30 seconds

Tags: c++11, serial-port, virtual, socat, gpsd

I am using a GPSD to feed GPS information to a virtual serial port. I'm generating the virtual serial port with `socat`, and I am listening to the virtual port using: `sudo cat /dev/pts/2`, where `/dev/pts/2` is the drive created by socat. The GPS signal is being obtained in a C++ script . The C++ script is giving me the expected output every 1 second, but the information stream simply stops after 30 seconds.

What options can I consider in either the `socat` arguments or the GPSDO arguments in my C++ script, to lengthen the time past 30 seconds?

Answer (score 0):

Socat in default setup has no timeout as long as both connections stay open. Apply options -d -d -d -d -lu to Socat to see in its output what happens!

Comment: I had a similar thought -- if it were throwing a timeout error, it'd show up in the `-d -d -d -d` option. I tried that, nothing remarkable showed up.